# Win10: "Factory Reset", OOBE & SysPrep with backup/required files?

Tags: windows-10, backup, sysprep

How do I create an image of a new Windows 10 install, with drivers and custom software, to donate/sell with a nice OOBE?

Alternatively: "Factory Resets" should be done from a local disk image of this Windows 10 - but how do I prevent Windows 10 from prompting with that "Insert Media - Windows requires files to finish resetting" prompt?

The end results I am looking for are:

- Someone to start the machine for the first time, they get OOBE and continue like normal.  They end up with Windows 10 with the my custom drivers/software setup and all latest Windows 10 updates completed.
- Future "Reset my PC" factory reset option restores machine back to exactly the way I gave it to them with custom drivers/software and windows updates.

The "factory resets" will be done completely with the local disk with a hidden backup partition.

---

I have a few desktops and laptops I've upgraded to Windows 10 over the years. Now, I want to donate/sell them off.

As far as I know, the process starts with:

- Install Windows 10 normally
- Go into audit mode
- Install required software / windows updates
- Sysprep image when finished and shutdown machine

What is not clear is "when" or "how" to take an image of the machine, on local disk, and have it be used by Windows 10 Factory Reset option.

With Windows 7, I previously recall a way to create a local "Disk Image/Backup" that can be used to fully format and restore a machine to factory defaults.  E.g., just like Dell and Gateway used to ship machines.

I am not talking about side-loading drivers of Windows media to supply with machines.  These machines were all old Windows 7 and 8 machines and obviously their media is outdated (not to mention, highly customized - like the GPUs and Wireless cards I've replaced in the laptops).

Therefore, I will NOT be providing "installation media"; instead, they will get a local disk image that the exact Windows 10 upgraded version that is legal for the machine, preconfigured with the correct drivers and custom software.

"What if the SSD fails?  How will they install with no media?"  Well then, they can replace it and resolve it themselves.  The Windows 10 activation is tied to the machine at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of additional research (I searched a lot BEFORE i posted the question!), I found the `scanstate` tool that is part of USMT.

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/11769-create-provisioning-package-windows-10-a.html

This will modify the "Reset my PC" recovery image to use[install] the currently installed software of the machine, along with all root files.  For example, I am shipping these machines with a `C:\drivers` folder.  After a full "Reset my PC", which erases everything and restores back to factory defaults (I am the factory!), my C:\drivers folder remains along with a newly installed version of the software I had installed (the drivers for the machine and overlays).

I just did this with Windows 10 ver 1607, tested it by Factory Resetting; it works perfectly!

Although the tutorial is a bit outdated, the latest instructions are on TechNet for the RTM version of Windows 10: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/deploy/usmt-scanstate-syntax